# Can I have an init func in a protocol?

Tags: swift, initialization, protocols, swift-protocols

When I try to implement my protocol this way:

```
protocol Serialization {
    func init(key keyValue: String, jsonValue: String)
}
```

I get an error saying: **Expected identifier in function declaration.**

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Why do you want this in a protocol? Why does it care how the type is created?

Comment: An object can have multiple init functions. Why not have one prescribed by a protocol as one that could get called?

Comment: That's because the `func` keyword right before `init`. Remove it and try it again.

Comment: @Mark: for example, `NSCoding`

Comment: Thanks Windor. That was it.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Yes you can. But you never put `func` in front of `init`:

```
protocol Serialization {
    init(key keyValue: String, jsonValue: String)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for not putting func in front of init? Thanks.

Comment: @LiweiZ: because initializers and methods are separate

Comment: Thank you. I guess I need to go through the developer docs one more time:)

Comment: OK, Swift is known for its style consistencies, and this is very inconsistent and confusing to newbs.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 44):

Key points here:

1. The protocol and the class that implements it, *never* have the keyword `func` in front of the `init` method.
2. In your class, since the `init` method was called out in your protocol, you now need to prefix the `init` method with the keyword `required`. This indicates that a protocol you conform to required you to have this `init` method (even though you may have independently thought that it was a great idea).

As covered by others, your protocol would look like this:

```
protocol Serialization {
    init(key keyValue: String, jsonValue: String)
}
```

And as an example, a class that conforms to this protocol might look like so:

```
class Person: Serialization {
    required init(key keyValue: String, jsonValue: String) {
       // your logic here
    }
}
```

Notice the **required** keyword in front of the `init` method.